# find if heap grows up 

Tags: heap-memory, direction

In reference to the link below which explains how to find if the machine stack grows up ofr down in memory ... i want to know if the following would be the correct way to find if the machine's heap grows up or down in memory.

[How would you find out if a machine’s stack grows up or down in memory? (JAVA)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1163977/how-would-you-find-out-if-a-machines-stack-grows-up-or-down-in-memory-java)

my code

```
void findHeapDirection(int *a) {

   int *b;
   b = (int*)malloc(sizeof(b));  
   printf("\naddress of a %x",a);   
   printf("\naddress of b %x",&b);

   if(b > a) 
     printf("\n>>heap grows up");
   else
    printf("\n>>heap grows down");   

    free(b);

  }
```

and call this function like this

```
 int *a;
 a = (int*)malloc(sizeof(a));
 findHeapDirection(a);
 free(a);
```

this was the output on my machine..

```
address of a 5417b0
address of b 28ff14
>>heap grows up
```

***Or is this question ambiguous as heap can never grow downwards?***

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a function call to test things with the heap.  That's there in the [linked question about the direction of the stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1163977/how-would-you-find-out-if-a-machines-stack-grows-up-or-down-in-memory-java) because the compiler might reorder variables on the stack within a single frame (or function).  It will not do that for function calls, so two successive `malloc()` calls without a method invocation between would be as effective as your example.

However, the difference between the numbers in your example is large compared to the difference between numbers in the linked question.  The heap does indeed grow in one direction, but that doesn't mean two adjacent `malloc()` calls will have a change in address value that implies that direction--it's more of a general trend.

The stack and the heap grow towards each other.  The simplest way to find out which direction the heap grows would be to find out which direction the stack goes (which you have from the linked question) and know the heap grows in the other direction.